# Send binary to the serial port

Tags: winapi, binary, serial-port, hex

To send a serial string character to the serial port.  I would need to call WriteFile(handle, "A", strlen("A"), ...)

However, what if I want to specify and send a hex or binary number?  For example, I want to send WriteFile(handle, 0x41, sizeOf(0x41), ...) ?

Is there a function that allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways.

The most straight forward for you though would be WriteFile( handle, "\x41", 1 ... );

The strlen() is redundant, since you know the length.

Comment: While you are correct in answering his question, it may not have extended Steve's knowledge.  By using "\x41" you did not explain this is actually an array of char.  Steve is lacking the understanding that you need to feed an array into this method.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to write one byte, it still needs to be in an array.

So you would need:

```
int buffer[1024];
buffer[0] = 42;

WriteFile(handle, buffer, 1);
```

See this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747(VS.85).aspx